# Best Programming Practise, C++ Headers and Include

Tags: c++, header, include

OK, I have done some looking around but to nothing.

As I have been learning C++, I have been told by some to have my includes stored into the .h file is available, and by others, to keep them in the .cpp file.

My question is what is the preferred industry standard and why?

Comment: IMO put your *includes* is every file that *needs* them. Don't rely on the `.h.` having included them and don't include them in the `.h` if only the `.cpp` needs them.

Comment: @Galik, Sorry that wasnt the question, but thanks anyways even though I already knew that :). Wahib Mkadmi Answered it though so all good now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Includes in the `.cpp` are only included when that one file is compiled, but the includes for the `.h` are to included everytime it the file is invoked.
Hence putting your includes in cpp files will most likely speed up compilation (less cross-referencing)